# Angular Universal Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Navigator'

Tags: angular, angular-universal, navigator

I am getting the following error in my `server.ts`

```
server.get('*', (req, res) => {
  global['navigator'] = req['headers']['user-agent'];
  ....
```

> ```
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Navigator'.
> ```

How to correctly assign the type ? I just upgraded from Angular 9 to Angular 10.

Comment: try `global['navigator']['userAgent'] = req['headers']['user-agent'];`

Comment: @Andrei - tried but then i am getting `Cannot assign to 'userAgent' because it is a read-only property`

Comment: `global.navigator = { userAgent: req['headers']['user-agent'] };` ?

Comment: ah, I see. then you won't be able to set it at all

Comment: @Gilsdav : Type '{ userAgent: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Navigator': activeVRDisplays, clipboard, credentials, doNotTrack, and 45 more.

Comment: Ok, Can I ask you why you need to set the agent ? Do you have conditions with it ?

Comment: If you have conditions in your code Angular, I'd suggest another strategy: Use a provider rather than directly using the userAgent. `res.render('index', { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }, { provide: 'USER_AGENT', useValue: req.headers['user-agent'] }] });`

Comment: @Gilsdav https://github.com/Ismaestro/angular9-example-app/blob/d41c85deb97366fa185f90c67aeab565bf7f40ef/server.ts#L127

Comment: Ok I can see you are using it only in `UtilsHelperService.isBrowserValid()`
So you can probably use the code I gived into the previous comment.
You also have to add (for browser part) the provider to your app.module `{ provide: 'USER_AGENT', useValue: navigator.userAgent }`.

Comment: try `global['navigator].userAgent=req['headers']['user-agent']`